# C++ Find specific element in vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector like below.

```
struct Personel {
    uint16_t personelId;
    uint8_t age;
}

std::vector<Personel> Personels;
```

Imagine adding 1000 elements as below.

```
Personel personel1;
personel1.personelId = 1;
personel1.age = 26;
Personels.push_back(personel1);
.
.
.
Personel personel1000;
personel1000.personelId = 1000;
personel1000.age = 42;
Personels.push_back(personel1000);
```

As it is understood from the code, `personelId` will be unique.
Without iterating each element with for and comparing, How can I get **index** according to `personelId`.

Below code not working: Because `int` not `Personel`

```
auto match = std::find(Personels.begin(), Personels.end(), 596);
int index = std::distance(Personels.begin(), match); //must return 596
```

Comment: unfortunately this question is better in terms of providing something more close to a [mcve] compared to the duplicate question. Anyhow, as you already got answers I thought I doesnt hurt to close as duplicate. Maybe someone will find a better one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `find` you need to pass value of the same type as vector value. The one of ways is to define oprator== for Personel, create pesonal with target ID and use find.  The other is to use find_if with lambda:

```
auto match = std::find_if(Personels.begin(), Personels.end(), [] (const Personel& v) {return v.personelId ==  596});
int index = std::distance(Personels.begin(), match);
```

Or, you may use old good `for` )))

Comment: Does Find_if have an advantage in speed?

Comment: @QweQwe algorithms arent faster than handwritten loops. They are as fast as handwritten loops. You can find a possible implementation here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find. The advantage is not speed, but readability and less opportunities to make mistakes

Comment: Compare with what? Compare with passing to `find` structure, `find_if` should probably be slight faster because of less overhead, but it is negligible. 
To my mind `distance` is very slow, difference is faster (match - Personels.begin()), and `for` is faster in your case because you do not need to recount iterator to index.

Comment: @AskoldIlvento iterate through for

Answer (score 2):

As you noticed, `std::find` will not work here, because you want to compare only based on the personel id, ignoring all other fields.

This is exactly what [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) is for. It has an additional parameter for supplying a predicate to be used during the search. Simply call `find_if` with a predicate that checks the personel id of the given element for the one you are looking for.